# Change update date in vba exc datepicker input tag

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change the update date on my work website, when I fill it in manually with my code and click btn everything is normal but running the entire code my website only returns the latest default date . Please help me with the code. thanks

```vb
Set EleChance = ieDoc.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_View_GiengBtn")
    Set inputdate = ieDoc.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_ngayNhapPicker_I")
    
    'Set Eleimg = ieDoc.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_ngayNhapPicker_B-1Img")
    
    Set BtDateB = ieDoc.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_ngayNhapPicker_B-1")
    Set BtClDateB = ieDoc.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_ngayNhapPicker_DDD_C_BC") '// Bt clear date
    
    If Not EleChance Is Nothing And Not inputdate Is Nothing Then
    

        For i = 0 To inputdate.all.Length
            If inputdate.all.item(i).innerText = "16/03/2024" And TypeName(inputdate.all.item(i)) = "HTMLInputElement" Then
                inputdate.all.item(i).value = "11/03/2024"
                
            End If
            
        Next i
        
        
        EleChance.Click
        
        Delay 1
```

```html
<table class="dxeButtonEditSys dxeButtonEdit_Youthful" id="ctl00_MainContent_ngayNhapPicker" style="width:100px;">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td class="dxic" onmousedown="return ASPx.DDMC_MD('ctl00_MainContent_ngayNhapPicker', event)" style="width:100%;"><input class="dxeEditArea_Youthful dxeEditAreaSys" id="ctl00_MainContent_ngayNhapPicker_I" name="ctl00$MainContent$ngayNhapPicker" onfocus="ASPx.EGotFocus('ctl00_MainContent_ngayNhapPicker')" onblur="ASPx.ELostFocus('ctl00_MainContent_ngayNhapPicker')" onchange="ASPx.ETextChanged('ctl00_MainContent_ngayNhapPicker')" value="17/03/2024" type="text" autocomplete="off"></td><td id="ctl00_MainContent_ngayNhapPicker_B-1" class="dxeButton dxeButtonEditButton_Youthful" onmousedown="return ASPx.DDDropDown('ctl00_MainContent_ngayNhapPicker', event)" style="-webkit-user-select:none;"><img id="ctl00_MainContent_ngayNhapPicker_B-1Img" class="dxEditors_edtDropDown_Youthful" src="/DXR.axd?r=1_36-dWD4f" alt="v"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I want to pass text into the input date tag and change the update date on my website.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you've already assigned the target input to a variable with the following line...

```
Set inputdate = ieDoc.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_ngayNhapPicker_I")
```

Therefore, you should be able to change the date as follows...

```
inputdate.Value = "11/03/2024"
```

Comment: Well I did that and everything failed, msg inputDate returned the default value and my website reloaded with the default value...

Comment: I've tested the code, and it seems that I'm able to retrieve the inputted date.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with new code:

```
 Set EleChance = ieDoc.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_View_GiengBtn")
Set inputdate = ieDoc.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_ngayNhapPicker_I")

inputdate.value = DateSerial(2024, 3, 11) 'Format("11/03/2024", "dd/mm/yyyy") ' "11/03/2024"

MsgBox inputdate.value '// Return = "17/03/2024"
```

HTML :

```
<input class="dxeEditArea_Youthful dxeEditAreaSys" id="ctl00_MainContent_ngayNhapPicker_I" name="ctl00$MainContent$ngayNhapPicker" onfocus="ASPx.EGotFocus('ctl00_MainContent_ngayNhapPicker')" onblur="ASPx.ELostFocus('ctl00_MainContent_ngayNhapPicker')" onchange="ASPx.ETextChanged('ctl00_MainContent_ngayNhapPicker')" value="17/03/2024" type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).